# Source of free dicom images of different color models?

Tags: image, dicom

I'm developing an tool for DICOM files. I'd like to test the tool with DICOM files that have images of different color models which are the following:

MONOCHROME2
MONOCHROME1
PALETTE COLOR
RGB
YBR_FULL
YBR_FULL_422
YBR_PARTIAL_422
YBR_RCT
YBR_ICT

Until now, I have managed to test my app with only Monochrome 1 and 2, RGB, YBR_FULL, YBR_FULL_422. Is there any source where I can find other types of images for testing purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of PALETTE_COLOR images at http://barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/

For the others maybe ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/datasets/wg04/ - the readme file indicates they have most of what you're looking for, but I haven't investigated fully.